# Transfer image across view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, imageview

On my iPhone app, I have two viewControllers (firstViewController, secondViewController), on firstViewController the user can select a photo from the camera roll and it then displays it in an imageView, however I need to also display it in secondViewController but have no idea how to.

Can you also please explain your answers in-depth as I am fairly new to objective-C

Here's my code:

firstViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIkit.h>

@interface firstViewController : UIViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *theImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *theImageView;
-(IBAction)selectExistingPicture;

@end
```

firstViewController.m

```
#import "firstViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"

@implementation firstViewController

@synthesize theImageView

-(IBAction) selectExistingPicture
{
    if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    theImageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)  picker
{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)switchSecondViewController {

    SecondViewController *viewcontroller = [[SecondViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
    [viewcontroller release];
}
// Default Apple code

@end
```

There's not much in secondViewController so I won't bother posting that code.

Comment: If You have image stored in "document directory" of your application, then you can pass name of image to next class, where you can use it to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Have a method in your second view controller of the type

```
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
```

In the method below after you create a viewcontroller call the method with the image as shown

```
-(IBAction)switchSecondViewController {
    SecondViewController *viewcontroller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
    [viewcontroller setImage:theImageView.image]
    [viewcontroller release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a property in second view so you can set the image from your first view some thing like this:

secondImageView is the property in secondView and you have to set it

```
-(IBAction)switchSecondViewController {

    SecondViewController *viewcontroller = [[SecondViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
     viewcontroller.secondImageView.image = firstViewImage;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
    [viewcontroller release];
}
```

Comment: This is great apart from the firstViewImage part, I presume I'm supposed to put the original image there but all I have is the UIImageView (theImageView) which gives me an error as it's not a UIImage, what should I put there?

Comment: viewcontroller.secondImageView.image = firstViewImage.image;

Comment: Now I'm getting the error SIGABRT on that line whenever I go onto the secondViewController

Comment: at which line your getting crash ? viewcontroller.secondImageView.image = theImageView.image (according to your code )

Comment: Yes, it's viewcontroller.secondImageView.image = theImageView.image;

Comment: Looks like you havent allocated memory that that image view

Comment: yeah true... i thought you have added image view from IB

Comment: Can I have some help with that? For some odd reason I can't seem to allocate the memory without getting errors (still trying to learn a lot of objective-c)

Comment: you should learn memory management http://memo.tv/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone